# How do I flatten a mesh with rounded corners and beveled sides

Tags: modeling, modifiers, subdivision-surface, boolean-modifier

[image]

Hey Guys!,

So I am modelling a apple watch by reference, and during the initial stages of modelling I inflated the sides a bit to make it close to the reference but after finished I saw that the sides are a bit too inflated for the buttons to be hidden underneath the casing.

For eg, This is how the actual product is :
[image]

Would really appreciate any topology tips or ways in which I can fix this issue as this has been the second time a sub-d mesh with different topology has come into my life.

Thanks in Advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select this center edge loop, activate the *Proportional Editing* option and *Transform Pivot Point > Median Point* and scale a bit:

[image]